# ABAP Interacción entre tablecontrol y PAI

Tags: sap, abap

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en SAP, la cual tiene una DYNPRO que tiene un table control con una estructura de datos. Habiendo utilizado el wizard que te da SAP en el PAI (Process After Input), hay un MODULE de modify el tablecontrol, el cual lo que introducimos por pantalla en el table control, con un MODIFY asignamos eso que hemos introducido a una tabla interna, mi cuestión es que todo el rato me falla y salta el SY-SUBRC a 4.

Código PAI:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola iNerZiA, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Comment: Una recomendación para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas: añade el código en modo de texto (eso ayuda a otros usuarios a replicar el problema) y explica cómo te falla exactamente (¿no corre? ¿recibes algún error? ¿cuál?).